# how do you separate each part of an array into another array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

so I have a string that is split at any period. It is then stored into the array "sentences". Now I want to split all parts of the array "sentences" by spacing. How do I do that?

my code so far:

```
string input = TextEditor.Text;
string[] sentences = input.Split('.');
string[] words = sentences[0].Split(' ');
```

this does not work though, obviously.

the output I want is if the string is: `hello world I feel great. How about you.`

output:

```
wordarray[0] = {"hello", "world", "I", "feel", "great"};
wordarray[1] = {"How", "about", "you"};
```

Comment: *this does not work though, obviously....* and why so???

Comment: @Rahul it gives me an error, I can't show you the error because it really doesn't define the problem, but just says its an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the words in one array use `SelectMany()`

```
string[] sentences = input.Split('.');
string[] words = sentences.SelectMany((sentence) => sentence.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```

**Edit 1**

For the fun of it you can get a histogram of words (count of each word) with

```
foreach (var item in words.GroupBy((word) => word).OrderByDescending((word) => word.Count()))
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Count()}");
}
```

Comment: To avoid empty words (from multiple spaces), use the following code instead `string[] words = sentences.SelectMany((sentence) => sentence.Split(new[] { ' ' },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();`

Comment: @DrummingAce it is all the power of `LINQ`

Answer (score 4):

So you want your result to be a `string[][]` right? Each sub array contains a sentence. And each item in the subarrays contains words that make up the sentence.

Just use LINQ:

```
string[][] words = sentences.Select(x => 
    x.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Rahul With the posted code, the length of `sentences` must be known at compile time, which is not likely to be possible.

Comment: @Sweeper it shows an error at `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: @DrummingAce Oops! I got a typo. See the edited answer!

Comment: If I use this, the place where I output the results: `Output.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.Where(s => s != "\n" && s != "\r\n"));` I get an error at the `!=` saying `!=` cannot be an operand of type string[] and string. If you can fix this then you have the true answer

Comment: @DrummingAce Oh I see what you need now, judging by the accepted answer. You want a `string[]` containing all the words in the text editor.

Comment: @Sweeper yes. Sorry if I created confusion

Answer (score 1):

You might want to loop through and get the inner arrays filled like

```
    string input = TextEditor.Text;
    string[] sentences = input.Split('.');

    for(int i=0; i< sentences.Length; i++)
    {  
      string[] words = sentences[i].Split(' ');
       //do some processing on this
    }
```